# How to get return value from python codes in python-shell of node.js?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

I want to get return value of tmp.py in tmp.js.
How can I solve this?

```
def function():
    return 'tmp'
```

```
const {PythonShell} = require('python-shell');
PythonShell.run('tmp.py')
```

Comment: A _file_ does not have a `return` value. A function does. Modifiy your tmp.py such that it includes the call to the function: `if __name__ == '__main__': function()`

Answer (score 1):

A *file* does not have a 'return' value.
A *function* however, does.

Either:

- modify your `tmp.py` such that the desired function gets called

  ```
  def function()
      return 'tmp'

  if __name__ == '__main__':
      var = function()
      print(var)
  ```
- or directly run the code in the shell

  ```
   const {PythonShell} = require('python-shell');
   PythonShell.run('import tmp')
   PythonShell.run('print(tmp.function())')
  ```